# Upload image to cloud storage from firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying so hard to upload one image from cloud functions
I am sending an image from the web to the cloud function using onRequest. I am sending a base64 string and the fileName. Now I was following different tutorials on the internet and couldn't seem to solve my problem.

Here is my code. I think I am doing something wrong with the service account json. Although i generated the json file and used it but still it didn't work.

I get the error of `The caller does not have permission at Gaxios._request` when i don't use service account json
And when i do use serviceAccount.json then i get this error `The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object` which is from `file.createWriteStream()` i think

Anyway here is the code can anyone please help me with this

The projectId that I am using is shown in the picture below

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const projectId = functions.config().apikeys.projectid; // In the picture below

const stream = require("stream");

const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });

const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
//  Enable Storage
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: projectId, // I did use serviceAccount json here but that wasn't working
});




// With serviceAccount.json code
// const storage = new Storage({
//      projectId: projectId,
//      keyFilename: serviceAccount,
//    });
// This is giving the error of: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
    
exports.storeUserProfileImage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, async () => {
    try {
      const bucket = storage.bucket(`gs://${projectId}.appspot.com`);

      let pictureURL;
      const image = req.body.image;
      const userId = req.body.userId;
      const fileName = req.body.fileName;

      const mimeType = image.match(
        /data:([a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.+]+).*,.*/
      )[1];
      //trim off the part of the payload that is not part of the base64 string
      const base64EncodedImageString = image.replace(
        /^data:image\/\w+;base64,/,
        ""
      );
      const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(base64EncodedImageString, "base64");
      const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
      bufferStream.end(imageBuffer);
      // Define file and fileName
      const file = bucket.file("images/" + fileName);

      bufferStream
        .pipe(
          file.createWriteStream({
            metadata: {
              contentType: mimeType,
            },
            public: true,
            validation: "md5",
          })
        )
        .on("error", function (err) {
          console.log("error from image upload", err.message);
        })
        .on("finish", function () {
          // The file upload is complete.
          console.log("Image uploaded");
          file
            .getSignedUrl({
              action: "read",
              expires: "03-09-2491",
            })
            .then((signedUrls) => {
              // signedUrls[0] contains the file's public URL
              console.log("Signed urls", signedUrls[0]);
              pictureURL = signedUrls[0];
            });
        });
      console.log("image url", pictureURL);
      res.status(200).send(pictureURL);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return { success: false, error: e };
    }
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the code where you use the service account.

Comment: Did that @VictorEronmosele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all I didn't give any serviceaccounts because I am using the firebase cloud functions as @Dharmaraj said in his answer
Secondly, this was a permission problem in the google cloud platform which can be solved by going through the following steps

Go to your project's Cloud Console (https://console.cloud.google.com/) > IAM & admin > IAM, Find the `App Engine default service account` then click on the pencil at far left > Click on add role > In the filter field enter Service Account Token Creator and click on it save and you are good to go

Found this solution from here
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/782

Answer (score 2):

```
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: projectId
  keyFilename: "" // <-- Path to a .json, .pem, or .p12 key file
});
```

`keyFilename` accepts path to where your service account is stored and the credentials themselves.

```
folder
  |-index.js
  |-credentials
    |-serviceAccountKey.json
```

If your directory structure looks like about then the path should be like this:

```js
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: projectId
  keyFilename: "./credentials/serviceAccountKey.json"
});
```

---

Do note that if you are using Cloud functions then the SDK will use [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) so you don't have to pass those params. Simply initialize as shown below:

```js
const storage = new Storage()
```

Comment: I did this but I don't think that this file is present on the server-side. basically in the cloud so i am getting this error. Although i have this in my local setup
error from image upload ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/swmcontactportal-firebase-adminsdk-hl76c-3ad043c522.json

Comment: @SulmanAzhar you don't have to pass anything if using Cloud functions (please check updated answer). If you are using your own server, then you'll have to copy the service account to the server.

Comment: Yeah i am using cloud functions and i removed everything so it uses default but that is still not working. No w getting this error
Error: The caller does not have permission
    at Gaxios._request

Comment: Can it be because of ```const bucket = storage.bucket(`gs://${projectId}.appspot.com`);``` this code. I am using the link provided in the storage tab of default folder bucket you can check that in this picture https://i.imgur.com/5aOHI9R.png

Comment: @SulmanAzhar try `storage.bucket("your-bucket-name")` instead of complete URL. In this case it'll be projectId

Comment: Thank you so much I have solved it. Apparently, there was a permission problem in the google cloud platform also gave the same bucket link like this ```const bucket = storage.bucket(`gs://${projectId}.appspot.com`)```

Comment: You should use service account of the project that you want to access.